# Read from file and save data in array

Tags: c++

I already have this method to read data from the File. If the input is not exits or empty then ask the user to input again. Then if it correct and have some data I want to save my data in array Dragon which have 4 attribute name, rider, colour, wingspan. But something goes wrong with this code and I can be able to save data. It mean after all the Dragon Array is empty and nothing in there. Any solution?

```
int loadFile(Dragon * dragons) {
    int index = 0;
    ifstream fin;
    char name[100];
    char rider[100];
    char colour[100];
    int wingspan;
    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter filename >> ";
        string filename;
        getline(cin, filename);
        fin.open(filename.c_str());
        if (!fin)
            std::cerr << filename << " is not exiting" << endl;
        else {
            bool empty = (fin.get(), fin.eof());
            if (empty == true)
                cout << filename << " is a empty file" << endl;
            else {
                fin.getline(name, 100);
                fin.getline(rider, 100);
                fin.getline(colour, 100);
                fin >> wingspan;

                dragons[index].setName(name);
                dragons[index].setRider(rider);
                dragons[index].setColour(colour);
                dragons[index].setWingspan(wingspan);
                index++;
                break;
            }
        }
        fin.close();
    }

    return index;
}
```

And main:

```
int main() {
    initialize();
    Dragon dragons[ NUMBER_OF_DRAGONS ];
    int currDragonNumbers = loadFile(dragons);
    run(dragons, currDragonNumbers);
    cout << " insert your closing message here" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `But something goes wrong with this code and I can be able to save data` what are you actually asking, what goes wrong?

Comment: This: `bool empty = (fin.get(), fin.eof());` doesn't exactly have the most pleasant of aromas. And you really should check your IO operations rather than assume they worked.

Comment: It's possible that you are passing an invalid pointer to `loadFile`. Can you show the code of the function from where you are calling `loadFile`?

Comment: What is the "something" goes wrong ? Maybe give delimiter argument to getline function can be helpful if your reading from file is wrong and it should be "is an empty file" but i don't think that matter:D:D

Comment: "something" went wrong was nothing in the Dragon Array. So it mean I can't take data to array. Nothing in there. @Ben

Comment: This is the method call loadFile()       int main() {
    initialize();

    Dragon dragons[ NUMBER_OF_DRAGONS ];

    int currDragonNumbers = loadFile(dragons);

    run(dragons, currDragonNumbers);

    cout << " insert your closing message here" << endl;
}

Comment: You should use `std::string` instead of C strings and use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays. As it is you don't show us the allocation of the `dragons` parameter, but you would need to at least send *size* so you don't go out of bounds.

Comment: The size of Dragon array we don't know yet. It depend on the input file which 4 lines : Name, rider, colour and wingspan and read it until EOF so we can know how many element we have. Sample file :                       Mnementh
F'lar
Bronze
29
Ramoth
Lessa
Gold
31

Comment: @RichardNguyen but you have `NUMBER_OF_DRAGONS` which *defines* how many you can actually store. Also looks like this would only read *one* entry at most (you break out of `while (true)` after reading one line of the file. Try stepping through the code and watch what happens.)